# PHP - Routing with Parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a RESTful API using Laravel.

In my `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/accounts/(:any?)', array('as'=>'account_index', 'uses'=>'accounts@index'));
```

My controller:

```
class Accounts_Controller extends Base_Controller {
public $restful = true;

public function get_index($id = null) {
    if(!$id)
        return Response::json(Account::all());
    return Response::json(Account::find($id));
}
```

I get 404 responses when I try any request `accounts/##`, but `accounts` works just fine. When I change my route to something that isn't `accounts` like:

```
Route::get('/accts/(:any?)'
```

My routing works as expected, and on top of that requests sent to `accounts` still work as well. Is it because I'm using `get_index` for my function name, so that it reverts to using the standard `http://localhost/controller/method/arguments`?

**EDIT** I have controllers being auto-detected:

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

Comment: What are your other routes? Are you using Route::controller? If so it needs to be defined after your other routes.

Comment: The only other route I have defined is the default home page that comes with Laravel, and Controllers are being registered with `Route::controller(Controller::detect());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define routes, the order in which these routes are defined matters. Laravel uses regular expressions to match the requested URI against these patterns, and the first one to match is used with no further processing.

`Route::controller('accounts')` is effectively matching `accounts/(:any?)/(:any?)/(:any?)` etc. If you were to test the url `accounts/index/12` You would get the expected result.

```
Route::get('/accounts/(:any?)', array('as'=>'account_index', 'uses'=>'accounts@index'));
Route::controller( Controller::detect() );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should become a comment under the question. If you feel that the last sentence answers the original question, I suggest elaborating on it and moving the initial questions to comments.

Comment: Sorry about that George, it was meant to be a comment and I was not paying attention. After getting more information from actaeon This is a real answer.

Comment: Ah, so registering a controller actually enforces the `http://localhost/controller/method/arguments` scheme. If I wanted to only do the routing by hand I shouldn't put in `Controller:detect()`.

I took the line out. Thanks for your help!