# Laravel Route Controller with Forced Parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pattern-matching

So i have checked out 
[PHP - Routing with Parameters in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326364/php-routing-with-parameters-in-laravel)
and
[Laravel 4 mandatory parameters error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628766/laravel-4-mandatory-parameters-error)

However using what is said - I cannot seem to make a simple routing possible unless im not understanding how filter/get/parameters works.

So what I would like to do is have a route a URL of /display/2 
where display is an action and the 2 is an id but I would like to restrict it to numbers only.

I thought

```
Route::get('displayproduct/(:num)','SiteController@display');
Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');

class SiteController extends BaseController {

public function index()
{

    return "i'm with index";
}

public function display($id)
{
    return $id;
}
}
```

The problem is that it throws a 404
if i use

```
Route::get('displayproduct/{id}','SiteController@display');
```

it will pass the parameter however the URL can be display/ABC and it will pass the parameter.
I would like to restrict it to numbers only.

I also don't want it to be restful because index I would ideally would like to mix this controller with different actions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using Laravel 4 you can't use (:num), you need to use a regular expression to filter.

```
Route::get('displayproduct/{id}','SiteController@display')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: Correct, all constraints are done using regular expressions, using {id} will allow anything to match. Take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Code Happy is for Laravel 3, check out Code Bright (for Laravel 4) http://codebright.daylerees.com/

Comment: Wow...if only i ran into this - that site needs to be up in the top 10 search results to avoid headaches. -tks for the link

Comment: @dragoon What If I want to provide choices for id, like only value 1,3 & 5 can be passed? How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You may also define global route patterns

```
Route::pattern('id', '\d+');
```

How/When this is helpful?

Suppose you have multiple Routes that require a parameter (lets say `id`):

```
Route::get('displayproduct/{id}','SiteController@display');
Route::get('editproduct/{id}','SiteController@edit');
```

And you know that in all cases an `id` has to be a digit(s).

Then simply setting a constrain on ALL `id` parameter across all routes is possible using `Route patterns`

```
Route::pattern('id', '\d+');
```

Doing the above will make sure that all Routes that accept `id` as a parameter will apply the constrain that `id` needs to be a digit(s).

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand that one - and I haven't seen anyone use that one yet

Comment: Sorry for being late on looking into your answer - it is effective if the pattern is an actual pattern. The Where is prefered if its digits because you can restrict it to be digits. Its about the equivalent of doing a preg_reg match comparing to is_numeric - is_numeric yields faster results

Comment: @azngunit81 I think this is a better option if you want to re-use a pattern - for the same reason for which we use functions. Also it does not matter what pattern you want to match against, this is also using regex.